# Searches for books whose title contains the keyword and returns them ordered by titles

Tags: java, sorting

Searches for books whose title contains the keyword and returns them ordered by titles (in alphabet order).

i dont know how to tackle this title search and im not asking for you to do the code for me but explain how i can tackle the question. thanks :P

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
* A collection of {@link Book}.
*/
 public class BookStorage {

private Book[] books = new Book[100];
```

public BookStorage() {

```
/**
 * Initializes the book storage with some arbitrary book objects.
 */
public void initBooks() {
    books[0] = new Book("Crickey", "Mahmoud", 200, Book.BookCategory.Design );
    books[1] = new Book("Thinking in Java", "Bruce Eckel", 1520, Book.BookCategory.Programming );
    books[2] = new Book("Easy Life", "Jeff Bezos", 10, Book.BookCategory.Database );
    books[3] = new Book("Soccer Star", "Ronaldo", 1000, Book.BookCategory.Design );
    books[4] = new Book("Hells Kitchen", "Gordon Ramsay", 500, Book.BookCategory.Programming );
    books[5] = new Book("York Itec", "John", 1600, Book.BookCategory.Database );
    books[6] = new Book("Gaming Designer", "Rebecca", 1100, Book.BookCategory.Design );
    books[7] = new Book("Computer Science", "Mahmoud", 200, Book.BookCategory.Programming );
    books[8] = new Book("Google", "Jason", 333, Book.BookCategory.Database );
    books[9] = new Book("York Soccer", "Carmine", 777, Book.BookCategory.Design );
}

/**
 * Uses the given book to update the existing book with the same title.
 */
public void update(Book book) {
    for(int i = 0; i<books.length;i++) {
        if(books[i].getTitle().equals(book.getTitle())) {
            books[i].setAuthors(book.getAuthors());
            books[i].setPages(book.getPages());
            books[i].setCategory(book.getCategory());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Removes a book by title.
 */
public void remove(String bookTitle) {
    // TODO Add your code here...
    for(int i=0; i<books.length;i++) {
        if(books[i].getTitle().equals(bookTitle)){
                books[i]= null;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Adds a new book.
 */
public void add(Book book) {
    // TODO Add your code here...
    int index = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    boolean invalidArg;

    if(books[index].getTitle().equals(book.getTitle())) {
        invalidArg = false;
    }
    else {
        invalidArg = true;
    }

    if (!invalidArg) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The book has been added");
    }
    else {
        int tempCounter = counter;
        for (int i = 0; i<tempCounter+1;i++) {
            if (books[i] !=null) {
                continue;
            }else {
                books[i] = book;
            }
        }
    }


}

/**
 * Gets a book by title.
 */
public Book getByTitle(String title) {
    // TODO Add your code here...
    for(int i=0; i<books.length;i++) {
        if(books[i].getTitle() == title){
            return books[i] ;
        }
    }

    return null;            
}

/**
 * Searches for books whose title contains the keyword and returns them ordered by titles (in alphabet order).
 */
public Book[] titleSearch(String keyword) {
    // TODO Add your code here...

    return new Book[0];
}
```

the last part of the code is what im trying to solve

Comment: its a program that has a list of array displayed on the gui and i would type a keyword on the textfield and the list would show only the ones with that keyword

Comment: where are the books? global variable or where can i fetch them?

Comment: Unfortunately there's a huge amount of information you have not supplied that is needed to provide some hints on how to tackle this. Is the volume large enough to require an index or is a complete scan good enough? Are keywords complex or just a straight string search? Does `Book` have a `hasKeyword` method?

Comment: i added more code hopefully its more clear

Answer (score 1):

A start would be - looping through the input dataset, searching for the keyword and using `TreeSet<String>` to store all your matches (in natural ordering). More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).